# simple parameter substitution in regexp_matches postgreSQL function

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table with a structure like this...

the_geom data

```
geom1    data1+3000||data2+1000||data3+222

geom2    data1+500||data2+900||data3+22232
```

I want to create a function that returns the records by user request.

```
Example: for data2, retrieve geom1,1000 and geom2, 900
```

Till now I created this function (see below) which works quite good but I am facing a parameter substitution problem... (you can see I am not able to substitute 'data2' for $1 in... BUT yes I can use $1 later

```
regexp_matches(t::text, E'(data2[\+])([0-9]+)'::text)::text)[2]::integer
```

MY FUNCTION

```
create or replace function get_counts(taxa varchar(100))

returns setof record

as $$

SELECT t2.counter,t2.the_geom

FROM  (

   SELECT (regexp_matches(t.data::text, E'(data2[\+])([0-9]+)'::text)::text)[2]::integer as counter,the_geom

   from (select the_geom,data from simple_inpn2 where data ~ $1::text) as t

    ) t2

   $$
 language sql;

SELECT get_counts('data2') will work **but we should be able to make this substitution**:

regexp_matches(t::text, E'($1... instead of E'(data2....
```

I think its more a syntaxis issue, as the function execution gives no error, just interprets $1 as a string and gives no result.

thanks in advance,

Comment: So you want to use the `$1` parameter to your function in place of the `data2` part of your `(data2[\+])([0-9]+)` regex?

Comment: yes, it is. As I said, if i directly put.. regexp_matches(t.data::text, E'($1... it is literally interpreted ($1), giving no result. I tried multiple syntax options without success. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `E'$1'` is a string literal (using the [escape string](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE) syntax) containing a dollar sign followed by a one. An unquoted `$1` is the first parameter to your function. So this:

```
regexp_matches(t, E'($1[\+])([0-9]+)'))[2]::integer
```

as you've found, won't interpolate the `$1` with the function's first parameter.

The regex is just a string, a string with an internal structure but still just a string. If you know that `$1` will be a normal word then you could say:

```
regexp_matches(t, E'(' || $1 || E'[\+])([0-9]+)'))[2]::integer
```

to paste your strings together into a suitable regex. However, it is better to be a little paranoid, sooner or later someone is going to call your function with a string like `'ha ha ('` so you should be prepared for it. The easiest way that I can think of to add an arbitrary string to a regex is to escape all the non-word characters:

```
-- Don't forget to escape the escaped escapes! Hence all the backslashes.
str := regexp_replace($1, E'(\\W)', E'\\\\\\1', 'g');
```

and then paste `str` into the regex as above:

```
regexp_matches(t, E'(' || str || E'[\+])([0-9]+)'))[2]::integer
```

or better, build the regex outside the `regexp_matches` to cut down on the nested parentheses:

```
re := E'(' || str || E'[\+])([0-9]+)';
-- ...
select regexp_matches(t, re)[2]::integer ...
```

PostgreSQL doesn't have [Perl's `\Q...\E`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Escape-sequences) and the [`(?q)` metasyntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-METASYNTAX) applies until the end of the regex so I can't think of any better way to paste an arbitrary string into the middle of a regex as a non-regex literal value than to escape everything and let PostgreSQL sort it out.

Using this technique, we can do things like:

```
=> do $$
    declare
        m text[];
        s text;
        r text;
    begin
        s = E'''{ha)?';
        r = regexp_replace(s, E'(\\W)', E'\\\\\\1', 'g');
        r = '(ha' || r || ')';
        raise notice '%', r;
        select regexp_matches(E'ha''{ha)?', r) into m;
        raise notice '%', m[1];
    end$$;
```

and get the expected

```
NOTICE:  ha'{ha)?
```

output. But if you leave out the `regexp_replace` escaping step, you'll just get an

```
invalid regular expression: parentheses () not balanced
```

error.

As an aside, I don't think you need all that casting so I removed it. The regexes and escaping are noisy enough, there's no need to throw a bunch of colons into the mix. Also, I don't know what your [`standard_conforming_strings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) is set to or which version of PostgreSQL you're using so I've gone with `E''` strings everywhere. You'll also want to switch your procedure to PL/pgSQL (`language plpgsql`) to make the escaping easier.